# Exception thrown while calculating Exponential moving average using pandas

Tags: django, pandas, python-3.7, stock

While calculating EWM using pandas I am getting below error.

> **comass, span, halflife, and alpha are mutually exclusive**

Code:

```
symbol = yf.Ticker(symbol_record.symbol)
symbol_his_data = symbol.history(start=today, interval='30m')
try:
    symbol_his_data['8_ewm'] = symbol_his_data.ewm(span=8, adjust=False).mean()
except Exception as e:
    print('Exception occurred while calculating 8 ewm:{}'.format(e))
```

Not sure if it matters but I am using django-celery and threading. So at a time max 5 workers are working on max 5 different symbols.